Super + space can't switch keyboard layouts when hiragana is active
I am using Ubuntu 24.04 with English and Japanese keyboards:
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources gives
[('xkb', 'us'), ('ibus', 'mozc-jp')].
The Japanese layout can input roman letters (capital A sign is in top-right corner of the screen); or hiragana (hiragana あ is displayed in top-right corner).
The problem is, that while I can reliably switch with super + space from English to Japanese, I can only switch back, if the Japanese layout is set to roman letters. Switching back from hiragana to English occasionally might work, but usually does not.
In a terminal screen, having hiragana active, the combination super+space almost always results in a space (that is: as if the super key were ignored completely).
I might have read somewhere that "this has to do something with 2-byte character encoding", but I can't seem to find the source right now. This was not an issue prior with Ubuntu 22.04.

The issue remains in 24.04.1.

The issue remains in 24.10, after a fresh install... The good news is that I can change the layout when the search screen is active, that is, in the terminal I press super once, and then I press super+space.

This might have been solved in ibus v. 1.5.31. Fingers crossed.
